# Search for an Xpath returning results outside an element with a specified attribute in scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm using the scrapy shell to grab all of the links in the subcategories section of this site: https://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/.

There's probably a more efficient Xpath, but the one I came up was:

```
//div[@id="subcategories-div"]/section/div/div/a/@href
```

As far as I can tell from the page source, there is only one `div` element with a `[@id="subcategories-div"]` attribute, so from there I narrow down until I find the link's `href`. This works when I search for this Xpath in Chrome.

But when I run

`response.xpath('//div[@id="subcategories-div"]/section/div/div/a/@href').extract()`

in scrapy, it gives me back the links I'm looking for, but then for some reason, it also returns links from `//*[@id="doc"]/section[8]/div/div[2]/a`

Why is this happening, since nowhere in this path is there a `div` element with a `[@id="subcategories-div"]` attribute?

Comment: Interestingly enough, changing my Xpath to 
`//div[@id="subcategories-div"]/section[@class="children"]/div/div/a/@href'`

did it for me. But I suppose my question of why my original Xpath didn't work still stands

Answer (score 0):

I cant seem to find any id with the name doc in the page You are trying to scrape, You might haven't set a starting response.xpath. do you get the same result if You should to change, so like:

```
response.xpath('//*div[@id="subcategories-div"]/section/div/div/a/@href').extract()
```

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/NdeBjOF.png) is what is looks like in chrome on OSX. I boxed the doc id.

Also, adding the asterisk does yield the same result.

Comment: or try the following xpath : //*[@id="cat-list-content-main"]/div/a/@href').extract()

Comment: could you maybe add a dump of the output you get to get a more visual picture of the output

Comment: //*div didn't work for me, so I tried both `*//div` and `//*/div` +  `[@id="subcategories-div"]/section/div/div/a/@href').extract()`. Both still yielded links from within the subcategories-div as well as those in the `//*[@id="doc"]/section[8]/div/div[2]/a`, which I don't get.

Comment: i'm not able to derive where the problem originates from it boggles my mind :) but at least you have a working version now